# forEach pushing last argument

Tags: javascript

Hey so I didn't really know how to write title for this post but I have a question.
Let's say I have a object inside function that I want to fill with data sent as spread operator argument. I am looping through data with forEach. My problem is that only last arguments are pushed into a final results array.

To make my problem clearer, here is some demo code:

```js
let result = [];

function takeArgs(...args) {
  let obj = {
    string: "",
    num: 0
  }

  args.forEach(e => {
    if (typeof(e) === "string") obj.string = e;
    else {
      obj.num = e;
      result.push(obj);
    }
  });
}

takeArgs("Some string", 10, "Some other string", 15);
console.log(result);
```

So if I was to log results array, I would get "Some other string", 15 twice in a result array. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you create a reference to object `obj` in a closure. `obj` is passed by reference, so it is allways the same, and so it is being overridden. Try to create a fresh object in each loop iteration:

```js
let result = []

function takeArgs(...args) {

  args.forEach(e => {
    let obj = {
      string: "",
      num: 0,
    }
    if (typeof(e) === "string") obj.string = e;
    else {
      obj.num = e;

    }
    result.push(obj);
  });
}

takeArgs("Some string", 10, "Some other string", 15)
console.log(result)
```

EDIT: there is likely also flaw in your if-else branching: you are only pushing `obj` to `result` if its type is not a string (or is your intention?).

Comment: Yeah it's a flaw in code, thanks for pointing it out :D

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is just a pointer to some place in the memory.
Pushing it twice to an array is the same as pushing two pointers, no matter how much you change them from push to push - all of them will be affected by it.

Using a very clean syntax of `es6+`, you can prevent this problem by just adding the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to line 12:

```js
result.push({...obj});
```

```js
let result = [];

function takeArgs(...args) {
  let obj = {
    string: "",
    num: 0
  }

  args.forEach(e => {
    if (typeof(e) === "string") obj.string = e;
    else {
      obj.num = e;
      result.push({...obj});
    }
  });
}

takeArgs("Some string", 10, "Some other string", 15);
console.log(result);
```

The spread syntax creates a new instance of an object, with content of the current `obj` there is, or in other words - a pointer to a **different** place in memory.
This way, the previous `obj` and the current one are not related anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's because you create a single object which you mutate in your loop. So the end state of that object will be from the last iteration in the loop. Then you *push* the reference to the object in the loop. This will result that every object in the array is the same object.

Instead create a new object for each item in the loop and pass that to the results array.

```
let result = [];
function takeArgs(...args){
  args.forEach(e => {
    let obj = {
      string: "",
      num: 0
    }

    if (typeof(e) === "string") {
      obj.string = e;
    } else {
      obj.num = e;
      result.push(obj);
    }
  });
}

takeArgs("Some string", 10, "Some other string", 15);
```

However, this will only push the object to the results array when value type is a `number`. So you'd probably want to add some logic to split the args into groups of two, so that you have string and number pairs.

```js
let result = [];
function takeArgs(...args){
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
  
    let obj = {
      string: args[i],
      num: args[i + 1]
    }
    
    result.push(obj);
    
  }
}

takeArgs("Some string", 10, "Some other string", 15);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I didn't even think about using obj to store data like this, thanks :D